get exact (x, y) coordinate of line
hi nice people i do a image processing by python and open CV.in my project coordinates must be same because the line do not change. my camera and my line never moved.
take photo from a picture.coordinate of line(top and down)
i use extreme point and detected line to get coordinate of top and down line(x1,y1 for top and x2,y2 for down).
but problem arrive when the coordinate of top and down of line are not same in different stages in my loop. i have more variance in x1 , x2 coordinate and y1, y2 are good without challenge for me. i even buy a more quality camera but no useful. i want optimize my code to get coordinate same in different times especially in x1, x2 coordinate. my codes is below and my output is:
(83, 250) to (92, 256
(177, 253) to (180, 256)
(231, 252) to (238, 256)
(186, 253) to (188, 256)
as you see x1 , x2 has more variance than y1, y2. i want optimize x.
thanks for putting me time and helping me. appreciate
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2
from math import sqrt

def captureImage():
    print('Capturing image')

    videoCaptureObject = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

    result = True
    while(result):
        ret, frame = videoCaptureObject.read()
        cv2.imwrite("Newpicture.jpg", frame)
        result = False
        videoCaptureObject.release()
        im = np.random.randint(50, 256, size=(256, 256, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
        return im


def processImage(im):
    print('Processing image')
    image = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Stk/Desktop/Newpicture.jpg')

    # Convert image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    # Apply Gaussian blur to reduce noise
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    
    # Apply edge detection
    edges = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 150)
    
    # Find contours in the edge-detected image
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    
    if contours:
        # Get the extreme points of the contour (line)
        for contour in contours:
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            x1, y1 = x, y
            x2, y2 = x + w, y + h
            length = sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
            
            return x1, y1, x2, y2, length
    else:
        return None, None, None, None, None

N = 4
for i in range(N):
    frame = captureImage()
    x1, y1, x2, y2, length = processImage(frame)
    if x1 is not None:
        print(f"Line coordinates: ({x1}, {y1}) to ({x2}, {y2})")
        print(f"Line length: {length}")
        from cmath import atan
        import math
        azimuth = atan((x1 - x2) / (y1 - y2))
        altitude = atan(length/280)
        solaraltitude = float(altitude.real) * (180.0 / 3.141592653589793238463)  # Convert complex to real
        solarazimuth = float(azimuth.real) * (180.0 / 3.141592653589793238463)
        print(f"Solar altitude: {solaraltitude}")
        print(f"Solar azimuth: {solarazimuth}")
    else:
        print("No line detected in the image.")
    
    time.sleep(5)

i first use HUOGH TRANSFORM LINE that has very variance then use extreme point it give me better coordinate but also variance in x coordinate.

to get the coordinates of the contour, use X, Y = contour.T

additionally, always check if .read() worked by seeing if ret is true.

That's quite a fat line to be detecting the ends of. Maybe you can add a second, zoomed-in picture, with the exact points you are interested in identified in red.

Not knowing which coordinates you exactly need, I can give you the following code for you to use as "tools".
First we load the image, your object is very distinct from the background, we can mask it quite easily:
im = cv2.imread("contour.jpg", 0) # read as gray
mask = (im<40).astype(np.uint8) # get the line thing

This code leads to this:

Now that we detected the object, we can get all the coordinates that are True by using the following line:
Y, X = np.where(mask == 1) # get the x and y coordinates

What you decide to do with these coordinates is up to you. In this example, I scattered the points and fitted a line to plot:
im = cv2.imread("contour.jpg", 0) # read as gray
mask = (im<40).astype(np.uint8) # get the line thing
Y, X = np.where(mask == 1) # get the x and y coordinates
fit = np.polyfit(X, Y, 1) # fit a line
plt.figure() # new fig
plt.imshow(im) # show im
plt.scatter(X, Y, 0.1, color = "r", marker = "x") # scatter the points as red
plt.plot(X, np.polyval(fit, X), color = "k") # plot the fitted line
plt.axis("off") # remove the axis

This leads to the following image:

Here we see the image, the points that are true, and a fitted line.
If you would like to use thinning, then check this post along with the useful links posted in it. If you would like further help, please comment below.
